# How to get info from this hashtable

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, hashtable

Ill try to keep this simple, but still understandable. If there's any confusion, let me know!

I got this hashtable:

```
private Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>> allChannels = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

I'm inserting clients/users with this method:

```
public void connectChannel(String username, String channel) throws RemoteException{
    allChannels.put(channel, new ArrayList<String>());
    allChannels.get(channel).add(username);
}
```

Now i want to use this method, in order to get a arraylist with users connected to a given channel(argument). How could this be done?

```
@Override
public ArrayList<String> getUsersInChannel(String channel) throws RemoteException{
    return **Code needed**   
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Btw guys, the connectmethod got several checks, but its pretty long, so i didn't bother pasting it, since i know that its working great.

EDIT: Since theres seems to be correct using return allChannels.get(channel) theres gotta be something else wrong with my JList. I've used these methods in my GUILogic to get the JList running. I've made 2 other JList working the same way.

```
DefaultListModel usersInChanDLM = new DefaultListModel();

public DefaultListModel getUsersInChannelAsDefaultListModel() throws RemoteException{
    if(!(getChannel() == null)){
        for(String a : cf.getUsersInChannel(getChannel())){
            usersInChanDLM.addElement(a);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
    return usersInChanDLM;
}

void updateUsersInChannelJlist(JList jList3) throws RemoteException {
    usersInChanDLM.clear();
    usersInChanDLM.removeAllElements();
    for(Client c : cf.getClients()){
        if(!(usersInChanDLM.contains(c.findName()))){
            usersInChanDLM.addElement(c.findName());
        }
    }
    jList3.setModel(usersInChanDLM);
}
```

So, im obviously able to see that the last method is the one screwing this up, since it adds all the clients in the list. But what should it say instead?

### Solution:

So, i made it!

```
    public void updateUsersInChannelJlist(JList jList3) throws RemoteException {
        usersInChanDLM.clear();
        usersInChanDLM.removeAllElements();
        for(String s : cf.getUsersInChannel(channel)){
            if(!(usersInChanDLM.contains(s))){
                usersInChanDLM.addElement(s);
            }
        }
        jList3.setModel(usersInChanDLM);
   }
```

---

Answer (score 5):

Either I'm missing something really obvious, or you're just overlooking the answer (which you already have in your code!)

```
return allChannels.get(channel);
```

One thing you should consider is that if you're calling this connectChannel method over and over you will constantly be destroying your arraylist (since you're calling new on it, every time you call that method), so in effect each channel is doomed to have one user in it at all times.

You should check to see if the array list is null and if it's not, don't bother to re-instantiate it (unless I'm missing what you're trying to do, which I very well might be).

Comment: I got that covered mate :) I just didn't paste all the code. 
 if (!allChannels.containsKey(channel))

So, i already had return allChannels.get(channel); actually, so theres gotta be something else wrong. The JList with usersInChannel shows everyone thats online.

Comment: It's much like IRC, where u enter a channel, and you're then able to see everyone else in the same channel you entered in a List. Which in my case is a JList

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@Override
public ArrayList<String> getUsersInChannel(String channel) throws RemoteException{
    return allChannels.get(channel);   
}
```

This line (you have it there) works the same way - `get()` method gives you the `ArrayList` and than you add an item.

```
allChannels.get(channel).add(username);
```

Comment: Yeah, thats what i thought too. I guess theres something else wrong. I did a systemoutprint on my JList which runs this

usersInChannelJList.setModel(gl.getUsersInChannelAsDefaultListModel());

I atleast know that System.out.println(gl.getChannel()); returns the actual channel that a user is in, so that shouldn't be the problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a error in your connectChannel method. You should not create ArrayList each time.

```
public void connectChannel(String username, String channel) throws RemoteException{
    ArrayList<String> ch = allChannels.get(channel);
    if (ch==null){
        ch = new ArrayList<String>();
        allChannels.put(channel, ch);
    }   
    ch.add(username);
}
```

Comment: I got that method sorted out, i just didn't paste all the code. Trying to keep it simple on the parts working. I just thought seeing how i add users into a channel would help :)